# Get request sender server's IP address to a PHP web service

Tags: php

i have a web service written in php that sites `a` and `b` and `c` are sending POST requests to (using ajax or etc.). i want to ensure that a forth website (let's say `d`) is not sending requests by checking the sender server's ip address. how can i do that? or any other ways to guarantee my web service is just getting used by the ones i want? thanks.

Comment: To get the IP address, you could use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` within your script.

Comment: Taking a stab into the dark here… you are offering an API where 3rd party website owners will embed something into their websites, so the visitors to said 3rd party sites will interact with your API from their browsers? Then see [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991004/securing-rest-api-calls-with-client-side-token/40991624#40991624). You have a *public API* and such restriction is not really realistic. The interaction is between you and *arbitrary members of the public*, not you and the 3rd party website.

Comment: It might be better to pass an authentication token from the remote sites that should be given access. If the token is missing, the server can not send data. This will protect against any IP address changes that might happen over time.

Basically, add to each request would have this POST variable `token=7a87asdh88hb89shksd`, if it is missing, ignore the request.

You could also grant each server it's own token, which would also make it easier to track which server is making the call and could be used in logs or statistics.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but it's not bulletproof. So don't hang any security implications off of it. I'm not sure what you're using to serve the PHP (ie Apache, Tomcat...) but look into configuring whitelisting at the webserver level.